# Driver installation (Intel PRO/1000) - Solaris 10 1/13

Tags: drivers, network-interface, solaris

I have installed Solaris 10 1/13 on a computer containing an Intel PRO/1000 card. My problem is that the OS don't seem to recognize the device, ifconfig -a gives me only the loopback adapter (lo0), I can find information that suggests that the driver should be included, and the system have a manual page for the device

```
man e1000g
```

I have tried searching for information about installing drivers, but for some reason I can't find much, and most information is about Solaris 11.

How do i enable the e1000g driver? any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: since the controller on that card was released *after* Solaris 10 was released (Solaris 10: End of January 2005, Intel PRO/1000 PT: 4th quarter of 2005), I wouldn't be surprised if there's simply no driver included in Solaris 10, even in the 1/13 release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/hcl/devicelist/index.html Solaris 10 1/13 *should* support your card. Check with  /usr/X11/bin/scanpci whether the card is recognized as one of these PCI IDs:

[image: List of PCI IDs mapping to device names, supported by drivers]

You should see the /dev/e1000g device file: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1475/e1000g-7d.html

(Of course, Oracle is, once again, so full of itself that you can see that page for a fraction of a second before they redirect you to a product landing page. You need to just download that link (`wget http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1475/e1000g-7d.html`), edit it and remove line 66, `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=solaris11'">` . Oracle stupidheads.)

Chances are you *can't* build a driver for your operating system yourself – after Oracle bought Solaris, they closed down the source, and if the driver was added after the 10/09 release wouldn't give their driver additions to OpenSolaris. Never worked with Oracle Solaris, though. However, really, the driver *should* be there, and it might just be a matter of figuring out how to assign it to the PCI ID your device has – if it can be found on the PCI bus at all.

Comment: The card is not recognized as any PCI ID, i have one "unknown" Intel device, though. Could be it. I also don't have any e1000g device under /dev. I will try to run the "driver installer" from the installation DVD.

Comment: well, it needs to be on your PCI bus, otherwise no driver could talk to it. Which means it needs to have an ID.

Comment: Do you have any idea how i am supposed to add the device? I guess step one is to add the device under /dev ?

Comment: no, you're turning things upside down. The device will appear as /dev/e100g as soon as the driver works correctly. First, you need to make sure it is physically visible to your operating system – hence the question to look at scanpci to see whether it's there (on linux you'd run `lspci`). If it's not there, no amount of adding drivers can magically make it work.

Comment: Ahh okay, i see, i will look further into scanpci

Comment: I can't get it to work, I suspect i could find a solution if I spend all my time on this, but life is to short, I installed Solaris 10 on a T420s instead, and everything works, it also uses the e1000g driver, but i guess its a different card. I accepted your answer.  Thanks for spending time on this!

Comment: What about just running Solaris in a VM? That sounds like much less hassle than setting up physical machines